# Wrong solution in geometric series

Tags: java

[from 0to15 and q=0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Nmw.png)

So I´m trying to realize this math problem in a java program, i got a solution, but it kinda is wrong. The solution should be 1.111111111111111, but my solution is

And my Code looks like this:

```
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        double q=0.1;
        double n=1;
        for(double i=0; i<15; i++)
        {
            n+=q;

        }
        System.out.print(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: so my output solution somehow got lost, so this is my output 1.0000000000000009E-15

Comment: The output i not what you claim it is. It's 2.5000000000000013, which is what I expect from that code. You forgot to divide q by 10 at each iteration I guess.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: yes youre right, the "+" should be replaced with a "*" and then it would be the output I meant.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```java
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    double q=0.1;
    double n=1;
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
        n+=q/(Math.pow(10, i));
    }
    System.out.print(n);
}
```

it's the series `sum of 1/ 10^k from k = 0 to 15`

EDIT: also i should be int, as k int the sequence, in order to have the less error possible

Answer (score 0):

You code is not following geometric series sum. You need add all items by incrementing the power from 0 to N where N is the limit. Here is the solution for 16 elements series from 0 to 15.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double q=0.1;
    double answer = 0.0;
    int N = 15;
    for(double i=0; i<=N; i++)
    {
        answer += Math.pow(q, i);

    }
    System.out.print(answer);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but we are supposed to do the whole thing without the math library

Comment: You can write your own pow function.

Comment: ```public static void main(String[] args) {
        double q=0.1;
        double answer = 0.0;
        int N = 15;
        for(double i=0; i<=N; i++)
        {
            answer += pow(q, i); //Math.pow(q, i);

        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
    public static double pow(double num, double times) {
        double ans = 1.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= times; i++){
            ans *= num;
        }
        return ans;
    }```

Comment: oh yeah, right. sorry im fairly new to Java and i thought it was part of te math library.